# Html input returns an empty string

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue with my html code where I am trying to get an input from a user to use in my functions, but all the methods that I've tried return an empty string rather than what I have been entering. I have looked at the other questions on stack overflow that pertain to this question however none of the solutions there have solved my problem and I was wondering if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```js
var myPlaintext = document.getElementById("mPlaintext").value;
var myKey = document.getElementById("mKey").value;
let keys = [];
let string = "";
function encrypt(plaintext, key) {
  let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key);
  return encrypted;
}
function decrypt(encrypted, key) {
  let decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key);
  return decrypted;
}
function encryptThis() {
  let encrypted = encrypt(myPlaintext, myKey);
  document.getElementById("encryptedText").innerHTML = encrypted;
}
function encryptAll() {
  document.getElementById("table1").innerHTML = string;
}
function AlertTest() {
  alert(myPlaintext);
}
function processData(myData) {
  string += "<tr><th>Key</th><th>Encrypted Message</th><th>Decrypted 
Message</th><th>Original Message</th></tr>";
  for (i in myData) {
      let encrypted = encrypt(myPlaintext, myData[i].key);
      let decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, myData[i].key);
      keys[i] = myData[i].key;
      string += "<tr>";
    string += "<td>" + myData[i].key + "</td>";
    string += "<td>" + encrypted + "</td>";
    string += "<td>" + decrypted + "</td>";
    string += "<td>" + myPlaintext + "</td>";
    string += "</tr>";
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://danycabrera.com/csc130/proxy.php? 
 key=1wqnh5q6cthLz1lyHTF6sqQhYB7rca6RUGJy57y2EOgY&sheet=Sheet1", processData);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
            <label>Enter a string to encrypt</label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="mPlaintext" placeholder="Plaintext"/>   
        </form>
        <form>
            <label>Enter a a key to encrypt the string by</label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="mKey" placeholder="Key"/>
        </form>
        <button onclick="encryptThis()"> Encrypt your message</button>
        <div id="encryptedText"></div>
        <button onclick="AlertTest()">Alert Test</button>
        <button onclick="encryptAll()">Encrypt All</button>
        <table id="table1" border="1"></table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try snippet below either this is your desired outcome.

```js
var myPlaintext = document.getElementById("mPlaintext").value;
var myKey = document.getElementById("mKey").value;
let keys = [];
let string = "";
function encrypt(plaintext, key) {
  let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key);
  return encrypted;
}
function decrypt(encrypted, key) {
  let decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key);
  return decrypted;
}
function encryptThis() {
  let encrypted = encrypt(myPlaintext, myKey);
  document.getElementById("encryptedText").innerHTML = encrypted;
}
function encryptAll() {
  document.getElementById("table1").innerHTML = string;
}
function AlertTest() {
  alert(myPlaintext);
}
function processData(myData) {
  string += "<tr><th>Key</th><th>Encrypted Message</th><th>Decrypted Message</th><th>Original Message</th></tr>";
  for (i in myData) {
      let encrypted = encrypt(myPlaintext, myData[i].key);
      let decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, myData[i].key);
      keys[i] = myData[i].key;
      string += "<tr>";
    string += "<td>" + myData[i].key + "</td>";
    string += "<td>" + encrypted + "</td>";
    string += "<td>" + decrypted + "</td>";
    string += "<td>" + myPlaintext + "</td>";
    string += "</tr>";
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://danycabrera.com/csc130/proxy.php?key=1wqnh5q6cthLz1lyHTF6sqQhYB7rca6RUGJy57y2EOgY&sheet=Sheet1", processData);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
<!--     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
            <label>Enter a string to encrypt</label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="mPlaintext" placeholder="Plaintext"/>   
        </form>
        <form>
            <label>Enter a a key to encrypt the string by</label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="mKey" placeholder="Key"/>
        </form>
        <button onclick="encryptThis()"> Encrypt your message</button>
        <div id="encryptedText"></div>
        <button onclick="AlertTest()">Alert Test</button>
        <button onclick="encryptAll()">Encrypt All</button>
        <table id="table1" border="1"></table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>    
<!--     <script src="script.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have found an answer to my question that I'm going to leave here in case anyone else who has this problem stumbles across this question. The short answer is that I was calling the variables myPlaintext and myKey at the start of the js file load and it was just grabbing the empty space that starts in the inputs. I have fixed it by creating a function to get the inputs and calling it as needed

```
var myPlaintext = "";
var myKey = "";
let keys = [];
let string = "";
function getPlainKey() {
  myPlaintext = document.getElementById('mPlaintext').value;
  myKey = document.getElementById('mKey').value;
}
 function encrypt(plaintext, key) {
  let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, key);
  return encrypted;
 }
 function decrypt(encrypted, key) {
  let decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key);
  return decrypted;
 }
 function encryptThis() {
  getPlainKey();
  let encrypted = encrypt(myPlaintext, myKey);
  document.getElementById("encryptedText").innerHTML = encrypted;
}
function encryptAll() {
  getPlainKey();
  $.getJSON("http://danycabrera.com/csc130/proxy.php? 
  key=1wqnh5q6cthLz1lyHTF6sqQhYB7rca6RUGJy57y2EOgY&sheet=Sheet1", 
  processData);
}
function AlertTest() {
  getPlainKey();
  alert(myPlaintext);
}
function processData(myData) {
    getPlainKey();
    string += "<tr><th>Key</th><th>Encrypted Message</th><th>Decrypted 
    Message</th><th>Original Message</th></tr>";
    for (i in myData) {
      let encrypted = encrypt(myPlaintext, myData[i].key);
      let decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, myData[i].key);
      keys[i] = myData[i].key;
      string += "<tr>";
      string += "<td>" + myData[i].key + "</td>";
      string += "<td>" + encrypted + "</td>";
      string += "<td>" + decrypted + "</td>";
      string += "<td>" + myPlaintext + "</td>";
      string += "</tr>";
 }
  document.getElementById("table1").innerHTML = string;
}
```